# Regex match() fails with 'is not a function' error

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm facing a problem using `match()` function in javascript to match a regex expression, when i call the function 2 times, the first call work but the second trigger `is not function` error.

Here is my code:

in my `mixin.js` file i have this:

```
function isNumber(params) {
    var regex = /^[0-9]+$/

    console.log(params);

    if (!params.match(regex)) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

export { isNumber }
```

and i'm trying to test if it's work by importing this function and call it twice :

```
import { isNumber } from '../../../mixin'

console.log(isNumber(3))
console.log(isNumber(4))
```

the first call run without error but the second trigger `match is not a function`

can someone help me please.

Comment: make sure to cast the integer into string first

Comment: "_the first call run without error_" No, it doesn't. It fails for the first call as well.